# Not getting German special characters in the automated email from oracle11g database

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, oracle11g

I have wrote a procedure in oracle database to send automatic emails, this emails contains some special German character like ü ö ä ß .

To store this special character into database I am using UTF-16 (decimal) values, like following:

ß = chr(223)

Example:

```
update sentence set question='wie hei'||chr(223)||'t du?' where key='name';
```

which is working fine and I can see this question in oracle sql developer as "wie heißt du?"

but when I tested automated email, in emails I am not getting this special characters.

I will highly appreciate any suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Codepage problem at the user which executed the script?

Comment: what is that and how can i troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Active code page: 850 at machine

Comment: What is the procedure?  What is your database character set?  What is the character set of the email?

Comment: How is the mail send? By an Oracle procedure (e.g. package `UTL_SMTP`) or by an external application?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by sending html email and using html code for special character like

```
Ä = &Auml; 
ä = &auml;
Ö = &Ouml;
```

and so on.